# Is there any option to remove ALL warning of was written to, but never read/Used?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Im working on maintained of large project. there is lots of warning(790+). most of theme are  **

> "variable was written to, but never read/Used".

** i tried one by one fixed but its take too much time. so im looking for fix all warning with any way. if you faced this kind of warning or error please let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance. :)

Happy Coding.

[image]

Comment: May be it is time to clean the code. Less lines, less bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately or not, but as one of Swift compiler collaborators stated, ATM it's not possible to turn off this warning separately from all warnings: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-turn-off-unused-variable-warnings/47356

Answer (score 0):

Select Menu `Editor > Fix All Issues` or press <kbd>⌃⌥⌘F</kbd>.